# How to properly use WAYLAND_DEBUG

Tags: gtk, embedded-linux, wayland

I have written a gtk program using C. The problem I'm currently facing is that the application exits sometimes with the message:
`Gdk-Message: 12:47:30.017: Error 71 (Protocol error) dispatching to Wayland display.`

I would like to debug some more, but I don't know how. I saw something about a `WAYLAND_DEBUG`-flag, but I don't know how to implement this in the command line (or if this even is a command line flag?).

The command I'm executing to start the program is `su -l weston -c "/usr/local/display /dev/ttySTM2"`.

How can I implement the `WAYLAND_DEBUG`-flag to debug further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to use the `WAYLAND_DEBUG`-flag.

In my case, I need to run:
`su -l weston -c "WAYLAND_DEBUG=1 /usr/local/display /dev/ttySTM2"`

Comment: Please consider accepting your answer if it's the solution. That way, other users know that the question has been satisfactorily answered.